# .htaccess - rewrite, first param optional

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to make rewrite rule for pages and language.
There are two possible options:

```
website.com/photos/photo1 => website.com?page=photos&menu=photo1
```

and

```
website.com/en/photos/photo1 => website.com?lang=en&page=photos&menu=photo1
```

I have this, but problem is when first param is optional...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(en)/(.*)
RewriteRule ^.* %2?lg=%1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?/?$ index.php?page=$1&menu=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Probably best handled by having a second block of RewriteConds + Rule for that case.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need the `RewriteCond` directive that checks whether the request maps to a physical file, since a request of the form `/photos/photo1` (without a file extension) is unlikely to map to a file (providing your regex is sufficiently restrictive). Assuming of course that *dots* are not permitted in the last path segment.

Unless you allow directories to be requested directly then you probably don't need the directory check either?

As in your code sample, you should rewrite directly to the file that handles the request, ie. `index.php`. This is omitted from your example URLs. If you omit it in the rewrite then you are reliant on mod_dir issuing an internal subrequest for the directory index.

For the language code I'll assume any 2 lowercase letters ie. `[a-z]{2}`. If this can only be `en` or only a select few languages then change as required (eg. `en|dk|jp` - using *alternation*).

```
RewriteRule ^(?:([a-z]{2})/)?(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&menu=$3 [QSA,L]
```

The whole first path segment (non-capturing) is made optional, with a capturing subpattern that provides the value for the `$1` backreference (which is *empty* when omitted).

For the `page` and `menu` path segments I've used the `\w` shorthand character class (rather than anything other than a slash, as in your example) - this matches `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_` (underscore) - so this naturally excludes the *dot*.

I've made the trailing slash optional, as in your directive, however it would be preferable to decide whether you allow trailing slashes or not. What is the canonical URL?

The only potential "caveat" with using a single directive is that when the lang path segment is not supplied then you'll get an empty URL parameter (but it is always present). eg. `index.php?lang=&page=photos&menu=photos1`. Although this would be preferable in my opinion.